# Strange data format

Tags: python, json, database, type-conversion, format

I am working with a database and i have a column about promotions. I am trying to understand what data format it is. It looks like JSON but I don't think that is. Can you please tell me some method or a program to convert this kind of string into a nicer version?
Thank you very much!
One row is like:

a:18:{s:30:"require_codentify_for_shipping";s:1:"N";s:12:"product_code";s:16:"duowhite_Br3_180";s:3:"sea";a:6:{s:4:"gtin";s:0:"";s:3:"uom";s:3:"PCE";s:5:"maktx";s:0:"";s:7:"con_spp";s:1:"0";s:7:"con_ppb";s:1:"0";s:5:"piece";s:1:"0";}s:15:"product_options";a:1:{i:307;s:4:"1855";}s:18:"unlimited_download";s:1:"N";s:18:"simple_replacement";s:1:"N";s:10:"promotions";a:2:{i:127;a:5:{s:7:"bonuses";a:6:{i:0;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:14:"give_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"72";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"P";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"127";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:1;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:16:"remove_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"72";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"I";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"127";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:2;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:16:"remove_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"72";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"R";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"127";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:3;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:16:"remove_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"72";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"W";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"127";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:4;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:16:"remove_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"72";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"Y";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"127";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:5;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:16:"remove_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"72";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"G";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"127";s:7:"pending";b:1;}}s:10:"conditions";a:3:{s:3:"set";s:3:"all";s:9:"set_value";s:1:"1";s:10:"conditions";a:2:{i:1;a:3:{s:3:"set";s:3:"any";s:9:"set_value";s:1:"1";s:10:"conditions";a:2:{i:1;a:3:{s:8:"operator";s:2:"in";s:9:"condition";s:10:"categories";s:5:"value";s:3:"361";}i:2;a:3:{s:8:"operator";s:2:"in";s:9:"condition";s:8:"products";s:5:"value";a:62:{i:761528658;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"900";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1516450244;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"901";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1712345851;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"837";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:156283028;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"838";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:2119663618;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"839";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1221242465;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"840";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:749103973;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"800";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1537301491;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"801";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1029174711;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"802";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1246807329;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"803";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:2055601473;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"999";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1272470761;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1000";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1021275263;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1001";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1512686139;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1002";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:758051501;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1003";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1286969586;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1004";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1001564264;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1005";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1564739106;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1006";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:489664701;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"984";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1781039147;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"985";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1671351298;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"989";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:56182245;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:3:"990";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:359159036;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1072";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1651467370;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1073";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:66326071;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1074";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1962098337;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1075";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:302354661;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1076";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:418110905;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1139";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:779547612;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1140";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1500627790;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1141";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1065839880;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1142";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1216372126;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1143";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:11276096;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1137";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1877798191;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1138";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1966167192;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1175";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:331872978;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1176";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:984356680;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1246";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:291962022;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1291";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:2005947108;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1292";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1350947825;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1310";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:662889319;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1311";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1098140963;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1312";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:913538485;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1313";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1474828266;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1314";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:552544128;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1315";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1176078650;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1316";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:824097196;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1317";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1583242179;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1318";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:693726037;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1319";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1909998817;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1371";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1386676589;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1414";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:631255547;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1415";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1129750463;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1416";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:877768489;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1417";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:395727737;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1435";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1375666202;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1557";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1099868265;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1608";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:914987263;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1609";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1447956764;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1610";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:558440846;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1611";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:1203736520;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1612";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}i:817413982;a:2:{s:10:"product_id";s:4:"1613";s:6:"amount";s:1:"1";}}}}}i:2;a:3:{s:8:"operator";s:2:"eq";s:9:"condition";s:9:"usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"65";}}}s:4:"name";s:13:"Promisiunea1B";s:12:"promotion_id";i:127;s:17:"short_description";s:0:"";}i:113;a:5:{s:7:"bonuses";a:23:{i:0;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:16:"remove_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"65";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"P";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"113";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:1;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:14:"give_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"31";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"P";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"113";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:2;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:16:"remove_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"31";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"I";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"113";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:3;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:16:"remove_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"31";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"R";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"113";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:4;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:14:"give_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"65";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"I";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"113";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:5;a:3:{s:5:"bonus";s:13:"free_shipping";s:5:"value";s:2:"16";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"113";}i:6;a:5:{s:5:"bonus";s:14:"give_usergroup";s:5:"value";s:2:"65";s:12:"order_status";s:1:"R";s:12:"promotion_id";s:3:"113";s:7:"pending";b:1;}i:7;a:5:{s

Comment: That's PHP `serialize()` format.

Comment: [phpserialize](https://pypi.org/project/phpserialize/) can decode it.